# Can an interface property of type [abstract class] be implemented as a concrete class in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Perhaps a bit of a weird question.

I have an interface IReservable that describes behaviour to make a objects "reservable". A class which implements it must have a list of reservations, and a few methods to handle creating/removing a reservation. The interface declares a list of reservations, which is an abstract class inherited by 2 concrete classes; one for a room and one for a chair (RoomReservation & ChairReservation).

Both the room and chair classes implement IReservable, and both will always create instances of only one type (Chair -> ChairReservation and Room -> RoomReservation)

Is there a way to make it so that IReservable requires there to be a list of Reservations, but the implementation can decide the concrete Reservation?

explained in code:

```
public interface IReservable
{
    ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    
    // Rest omitted for brevity
}

public class Room : IReservable
{
    // Can I make this RoomReservation only?
    public ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}

public class Seat : IReservable
{
    // And can I make this ChairReservation only?
    public ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

It isn't necessary to do this, but I still wondered whether or not it was actually possible; since I can't find any examples of it.

Comment: You can do this with generics and a type constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this by using generics. For example

First let's assume you have some classes like this:

```
public abstract class Reservation { }

public class ChairReservation : Reservation { }
public class RoomReservation : Reservation { }
```

Now your interface would change to this, note the type constraint to make sure the reservations are always derived from `Reservation`:

```
public interface IReservable<TReservation> 
    where TReservation : Reservation
{
    ICollection<TReservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

And now your `Room` and `Seat` classes would be something like this:

```
public class Room : IReservable<RoomReservation>
{
    public ICollection<RoomReservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}

public class Seat : IReservable<ChairReservation>
{
    public ICollection<ChairReservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! @DilshodK noted that such an approach would not work in Entity Framework, but I don't really like the Explicit Interface Implementation either; it seems quite cluttered and unreadable. Do you know of another method to make this approach compatible with Entity Framework?

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582647/can-an-interface-property-of-type-abstract-class-be-implemented-as-a-concrete/69582747#comment122991248_69582905)

Comment: @DavidG Can you show example of mapping one-to-many association using generic interfaces? I had some scenarios but I couldn't use generic interfaces on making associations

Answer (score 1):

Even though the suggested generic interface technique works, I usually have a hard time dealing with generic interfaces. One of the advantages of interfaces is polymorphism. By using a generic interface your different implementations won't have a common base type so you will lose polymorphism. i.e., you can't do this:

```
IReservable reservable;
reservable = new Room();
reservable = new Seat();
Console.WriteLine(reservable.Reservations.Count);
```

If you never intended to take advantage of polymorphism, using a generic interface is enough (however, you may ask yourself why you need an interface in this case). Otherwise my suggestion is to use two different interfaces, one for reading reservations and one for reading and modifying:

```
interface IReservable
{
    IEnumerable<Reservation> Reservations { get; }
}

interface IReservable<TReservation> : IReservable
    where TReservation : Reservation
{
    new ICollection<TReservation> Reservations { get; }

    // Reservation methods
}

public class Room : IReservable<RoomReservation>
{
    public ICollection<RoomReservation> Reservations { get; }

    IEnumerable<Reservation> IReservable.Reservations => Reservations;
}
```

And then you will be able to use polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here to use generics as @DavidG showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69582747/8825020)

But if for some reason you cannot use generics you can use [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

It will be something like this:

```
public class Room : IReservable
{
    IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations;
    ICollection<Reservation> IReservable.Reservations { get { return (ICollection<Reservation>)reservations; } set { reservations = value; } }
    public ICollection<RoomReservation> Reservations { get { return (ICollection<RoomReservation>)reservations.Cast<RoomReservation>(); } set { reservations = value; } }
}

public class Seat : IReservable
{
    IEnumerable<Reservation> reservations;
    ICollection<Reservation> IReservable.Reservations { get { return (ICollection<Reservation>)reservations; } set { reservations = value; } }
    public ICollection<SeatReservation> Reservations { get { return (ICollection<SeatReservation>)reservations.Cast<SeatReservation>(); } set { reservations = value; } }
}
```

Comment: Generics work fine for me, and are the preferable method in my case it seems. I do wonder now, in what situation would you be forced to use Explicit Interface Implementation because you can't use generics?

Comment: I think this is bad, because `room.Reservations.Add(...)` won't do what you expect -- it will add the room to a copy of the reservations, and won't alter `room.Reservations`

Comment: @NicolasVanDamme, For example, if you are using entity framework it will not be possible to use generics in the model. In that case using explicit interface implementation will be very helpful

Comment: @DilshodK Ah, that's unfortunate because I will be using EF Core. I'll need to rereview what will work for me then I suppose.

Comment: @PharazFadaei I fixed the code, but I am not sure it is a good way. It is open for suggestion

Comment: Generics work perfectly fine in EF, you just need to use the concrete classes as the entities. I do this all the time.

Comment: @DavidG Hmm, can you show one example of mapping one-to-many association?

Comment: You can still break that in all sorts of interesting ways, such as [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IiulR9) and [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RF0msO). There's fundamentally no way to do this: you cannot safely expose two views over the same collection, where one view has an element type which is a subtype of the other view's element type, and both views let you add and remove elements.